# Shutdown (a script) one raspberry pi with another raspberry pi

Tags: python, button, ssh, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on a school project. We need to be able to shutdown (and maybe restart) a pythonscript that is running on another raspberry pi using a button.

I thought that the easiest thing, might just be to shutdown the pi from the other pi. But I have no experience on this subject.

I don't need an exact guide (I appreciate all the help I can get) but does anyone know how one might do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way I imagine is first making the python program connect via ssh to the pi you can to shutdown. You can see how to do it here: [How to make a ssh connection with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188970/how-to-make-a-ssh-connection-with-python)

Here you have what would be the adapted version for this script

```
from pexpect import pxssh
s = pxssh.pxssh()
if not s.login('localhost', 'myusername', 'mypassword'):
    print("SSH session failed on login.")
    print(str(s))
else:
    s.sendline('sudo shutdown -h')
    print("Shutdown command sent")
    s.logout()
```

You may then change it to make it more suitable for you, or if needed add a second s.sendline() containing the pi password if it is asked, as you are using the sudo which normally prompts for a password.

If you want to execute it with a button here is another answer that may help you: [When press button, python script runs automatically on Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149547/when-press-button-python-script-runs-automatically-on-raspberry-pi)

You may need to change the pins number on there so they matches the ones you want to use for your button.

Answer (score 0):

Well first we should ask if the PI  you are trying to shutdown is connect to a network ? (LAN or the internet, doesn't matter).

If the answer is yes, you can simply connect to your PI through SSH, and call shutdown.sh.

I don't know why you want another PI, you can do it through any device connected to the same network as your first PI (Wi-Fi or ethernet if LAN, or simply from anytwhere if it's open to the internet).

You could make a smartphone app, or any kind or code that can connect to SSH (all of them).